# Android Listview : Display Item details onItemClic

Tags: android, android-intent, listviewitem, onitemclicklistener

I have been working on a e-commerce application for a while, and now I have a ListView that displays a list of products - Each products = 1 ImageView and some TextViews-.

I set an onItemClick listener on that ListView, the event that I want to occur when I click on  one of that listView products is, Start the i new Activity, 'ProductDetails' that displays more informations on the product I have clicked on.

I have already asked this question somewhere else, but I didn't get a clear answer,
They said that I have to create a new 'list\details' project, but this can't happen now, as I've working on that project for like 20 days, and can't start all over again.

Comment: the approach is correct. what is your issue?

Comment: I don't know how to send the item data from the allProducts activity to the productDetails activity that will display them using another Layout, the data i want to send is the view witch contains the product informations + other TextViews that are not in the View that i want to send.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't send a `TextView` or an `ImageView` from `Activity` to `Activity`. what you can send instead is it's contents. so for example if you want to pass the information from the `TextView` you will need to pass the source `String` that is displayed there (Or extract the `String` from the `TextView`) you do that by passing a `Bundle` from the calling `Activity` to the invoked one or simply by putting it as an `Extra`:

```
intent.putExtra("string name", value);
```

and in the following `Activity` you get this data:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
bundle = intent.getExtras();
bundle.getString("string name");
```

Then in the following `Activity` create a `TextView` with the passed `String`.
Same way is handled with the `ImageView` by passing the it's path.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I have posted an answer but was only a link to another site so it was deleted :-(

Here I come again with what could be the solution:

In your first activity, you need to use `intent.putExtra(...)` and retrieve the datas in your second activity with `intent.getExtra(...)`.

#### Example activity 1:

```
i.putExtra("title01", yourDataCollection.get(position).get(KEY_TITLE01));
```

#### Activity 2 :

```
this.title01 = i.getStringExtra("title01");
```

There is a full project here : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/507651/Customized-Android-ListView-with-Image-and-Text

Comment: what is the point in posting the same answer 15 minutes after?

Comment: sorry my post was deleted a few hours ago due to lack of details in my answer (i only provided the link to the page). Here i explained a little bit more + the link to the source code. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Android uses intent to allow `Activity`s to interact. If you want to show a details of product, probably you have a `Class` that describe that product and with the information it holds you fill up your `ListView`. If you let the `class Product implements Serializable` you can use  [Intent.putExtra(String name, Serializable obj)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable%29), to pass the Product description between `Activity`s. In `ProductDetailsActivity` you can use:

```
getIntent(). getSerializableExtra (String name)
```

to retrive the serializable you put inside the Intent you created to start `ProductDetailsActivity`

Comment: If you have a link to a tutorial for using that Serializable please send it to me, thank's for your help.

Comment: you do need a tutorial, the class that describes a Product has only to implement the Serializable interface. that`s all

Answer (score 1):

If you pass your model class around many times using `Intent`, perhaps it could implement the `Parcelable` interface for convenience. For example:

```
    class ProductData implements Parcelable {
        protected String name;
        protected String someOtherData;

        public static final Parcelable.Creator<ProductData> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ProductData>() {

            @Override
            public ProductData createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
                return new ProductData(source);
            }

            @Override
            public ProductData[] newArray(int size) {
                return new ProductData[size];
            }
         };

        public ProductData(){
        }

        public ProductData(Parcel source){
            readFromParcel(source);
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeString(name);
            dest.writeString(someOtherData);
        }

        public void readFromParcel(Parcel source){
            name = source.readString();
            someOtherData = source.readString();
        }

        // Here goes the rest of your model code
    }
```

Then you can easily pass the object to another `Activity` using an `Intent`:

```
intent.putExtra("product", productData);
```

and later get the data using

```
ProductData productData = intent.getParcelableExtra("product");
```